# Managed resource closing when inside another managed resource

Tags: scala, resources, managed, scala-arm

I'm using scala-arm and I have a code similar to this one:

```
val pathList = List("wrongPath1", "path2", "path3")
val enumerator: Enumerator[Array[Byte]] = Enumerator.outputStream { os =>
    managed(new ZipOutputStream(os)).map { zip =>
        pathList.map(pdfPath => {
            managed(new FileInputStream(pdfPath)).map(new BufferedSource(_)(Codec.ISO8859)).map { inputSrc =>
                zip.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(documentName))
                inputSrc map { c: Char => zip.write(c) }
                zip.closeEntry()
            }.either match {
                case Left(errorList) => 
                    Logger.error("Missing doc")
                case Right(_) =>
                    Logger.error("Doc found")
            }
        })
    }.opt match {
        case None => Logger.error("ZIP FAILED")
        case Some(_) => Logger.error("ZIP SUCCEED")
    }
}
```

If managed resources "FileInputStream" or "BufferedSource" fail, then the "ZipOutputStream" also fails and I only see "ZIP FAILED" message in the console. I never see the "Missing doc" log.

If one path fails, then I need to continue adding all other files to the zip file. How can I achieve that?

Comment: With the `foreach` inside the top `managed` resource, you are side-effecting rather than monadically composing the resources.

Comment: I just updated the code, now I'm using `map` instead of `foreach`, but the issue remains there.